# Rename bones name

Tags: armature, bones, collada

I want to export a scene to collada to load it in Android openGl ES2, if I have many meshes each one has its own armature I noticed the root bone of all armatures by default called Bone, in collada I have to get skeleton from its name so if I let names as they are there is a conflict in names occurred, my question is am I have to rename bones before exporting to solve this or there is another solution?

Comment: This can be done via a script.  Do you also have a vertex group named "Bone" on each mesh assigned to each armature?

Comment: Yes I have  vertex groups for each bone called with its name